# Role/group based state restriction from one state to other state in Azure DevOps Services

Tags: azure-devops, state, transition, restriction

In Azure DevOps on-premises (XML process template), we can specify only particular group of users  allowed to do perform state transition from particular state to another.
**Ex**=> Transition from "**Active**" to "**On Hold**" state allowed only for the "Business Analyst" user group.
In Azure Devops services (inherited process model), we don’t have any option to restrict state transition based on the groups(roles) when transition from one state and another by using rules.
Please let us know how to achieve this in Azure DevOps Services(cloud).

Below is the scenario:

- Business analyst group => "Active" to "On Hold" (only business analyst group users allowed to change the state from "Active" to "On Hold")
- TechLead group => "Development" to "On Hold" (only TechLead group users allowed to change the state from "Development" to "On Hold")
- Business analyst group => "Deployment" to "on Hold" (only business analyst group users allowed to change the state from "Deployment" to "On Hold")

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported for inherited process model.

Currently it's only supported to restrict the target state of the WIT, but not original state.

In addition, for the state change logic, if you have any other states, eg: `new` state, TechLead group users can change state from "Development" to "New", then from "New" to "On Hold" instead.

There are already many discussion in link [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-specifying-state-transitions-when-using-inhe/365830), the [workaround](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-specifying-state-transitions-when-using-inhe/365830#T-N872539) doesn't work any more since state cannot be set as readonly now.

[image]